# I'm getting this whenever I open terminal

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, bashrc

How do I fix it :/

```
declare -x CLUTTER_IM_MODULE="xim"
declare -x CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/home/ahmed/catkin_ws/devel:/opt/ros/indigo"
declare -x COLORTERM="gnome-terminal"
declare -x COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE="ubuntu"
declare -x CPATH="/home/ahmed/catkin_ws/devel/include:/opt/ros/indigo/include"
declare -x DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-OnoUlUWdaJ"
declare -x DEFAULTS_PATH="/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path"
declare -x DESKTOP_SESSION="ubuntu"
declare -x DISPLAY=":0"
declare -x GDMSESSION="ubuntu"
declare -x GDM_LANG="en_US"
declare -x GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID="this-is-deprecated"
declare -x GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL="/run/user/1000/keyring-LjhWLh"
declare -x GNOME_KEYRING_PID="1740"
declare -x GPG_AGENT_INFO="/run/user/1000/keyring-LjhWLh/gpg:0:1"
declare -x GTK_IM_MODULE="ibus"
declare -x GTK_MODULES="overlay-scrollbar:unity-gtk-module"
declare -x HOME="/home/ahmed"
declare -x IM_CONFIG_PHASE="1"
declare -x INSTANCE="Unity"
declare -x JOB="gnome-session"
declare -x LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LANGUAGE="en_US"
declare -x LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/ahmed/catkin_ws/devel/lib:/home/ahmed/catkin_ws/devel/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/opt/ros/indigo/lib:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"
declare -x LESSCLOSE="/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s"
declare -x LESSOPEN="| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s"
declare -x LOGNAME="ahmed"
declare -x LS_COLORS="rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:"
declare -x MANDATORY_PATH="/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path"
declare -x NINJABLOCK_BRIDGE_GLOBAL_ADDRESS="localhost"
declare -x NINJABLOCK_BRIDGE_GLOBAL_PORT="5555"
declare -x NINJABLOCK_BRIDGE_LOCAL_ADDRESS="localhost"
declare -x NINJABLOCK_BRIDGE_LOCAL_PORT="5555"
declare -x NINJABLOCK_TARGET_CONFIG="/opt/ros/indigo/share/rocon_ninjablock_bridge/resources/default.json"
declare -x OLDPWD
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/cuda/bin:/home/ahmed/catkin_ws/devel/bin:/opt/ros/indigo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
declare -x PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/home/ahmed/catkin_ws/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/home/ahmed/catkin_ws/devel/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig"
declare -x PWD="/home/ahmed"
declare -x PYTHONPATH="/home/ahmed/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"
declare -x QT4_IM_MODULE="xim"
declare -x QT_IM_MODULE="ibus"
declare -x QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME="appmenu-qt5"
declare -x ROCON_RTSP_CAMERA_RELAY_URL="rtsp://user:password<at>localhost:port/videoMain "
declare -x ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES="/home/ahmed/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp"
declare -x ROS_DISTRO="indigo"
declare -x ROS_ETC_DIR="/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros"
declare -x ROS_MASTER_URI="http://localhost:11311"
declare -x ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="/home/ahmed/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks"
declare -x ROS_ROOT="/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros"
declare -x SELINUX_INIT="YES"
declare -x SESSIONTYPE="gnome-session"
declare -x SHELL="/bin/bash"
declare -x SHLVL="1"
declare -x SMARTTHINGS_BRIDGE_GLOBAL_ADDRESS="localhost"
declare -x SMARTTHINGS_BRIDGE_GLOBAL_PORT="5566"
declare -x SMARTTHINGS_BRIDGE_LOCAL_ADDRESS="localhost"
declare -x SMARTTHINGS_BRIDGE_LOCAL_PORT="5566"
declare -x SMARTTHINGS_TARGET_CONFIG="/opt/ros/indigo/share/rocon_smartthings_bridge/resources/default.json"
declare -x SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/1000/keyring-LjhWLh/ssh"
declare -x TERM="xterm"
declare -x TEXTDOMAIN="im-config"
declare -x TEXTDOMAINDIR="/usr/share/locale/"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR="asus_xtion_pro"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_BASE="kobuki"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_BATTERY="/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_GAZEBO_MAP_FILE="/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_gazebo/maps/playground.yaml"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_GAZEBO_WORLD_FILE="/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/playground.world"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_INTERACTIONS_LIST="[turtlebot_bringup/admin.interactions, turtlebot_bringup/documentation.interactions, turtlebot_bringup/pairing.interactions, turtlebot_bringup/visualisation.interactions]"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_MAP_FILE="/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_navigation/maps/willow-2010-02-18-0.10.yaml"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_NAME="turtlebot"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_RAPP_PACKAGE_BLACKLIST="[]"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_RAPP_PACKAGE_WHITELIST="[rocon_apps, turtlebot_rapps]"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_SERIAL_PORT="/dev/kobuki"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_SIMULATION="false"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_STACKS="hexagons"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_STAGE_MAP_FILE="/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_stage/maps/maze.yaml"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_STAGE_WORLD_FILE="/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_stage/maps/stage/maze.world"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_STDR_MAP_FILE="/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_stdr/maps/sparse_obstacles.yaml"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_TYPE="turtlebot"
declare -x UPSTART_EVENTS="started starting"
declare -x UPSTART_INSTANCE=""
declare -x UPSTART_JOB="unity-settings-daemon"
declare -x UPSTART_SESSION="unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1742"
declare -x USER="ahmed"
declare -x VTE_VERSION="3409"
declare -x WINDOWID="54530742"
declare -x XAUTHORITY="/home/ahmed/.Xauthority"
declare -x XDG_CONFIG_DIRS="/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg"
declare -x XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="Unity"
declare -x XDG_DATA_DIRS="/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/"
declare -x XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR="/var/lib/lightdm-data/ahmed"
declare -x XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"
declare -x XDG_SEAT="seat0"
declare -x XDG_SEAT_PATH="/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_ID="c2"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_PATH="/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0"
declare -x XDG_VTNR="7"
declare -x XMODIFIERS="@im=ibus"
declare -x CLUTTER_IM_MODULE="xim"
declare -x CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/home/ahmed/catkin_ws/devel:/opt/ros/indigo"
declare -x COLORTERM="gnome-terminal"
declare -x COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE="ubuntu"
declare -x CPATH="/home/ahmed/catkin_ws/devel/include:/opt/ros/indigo/include"
declare -x DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-OnoUlUWdaJ"
declare -x DEFAULTS_PATH="/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path"
declare -x DESKTOP_SESSION="ubuntu"
declare -x DISPLAY=":0"
declare -x GDMSESSION="ubuntu"
declare -x GDM_LANG="en_US"
declare -x GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID="this-is-deprecated"
declare -x GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL="/run/user/1000/keyring-LjhWLh"
declare -x GNOME_KEYRING_PID="1740"
declare -x GPG_AGENT_INFO="/run/user/1000/keyring-LjhWLh/gpg:0:1"
declare -x GTK_IM_MODULE="ibus"
declare -x GTK_MODULES="overlay-scrollbar:unity-gtk-module"
declare -x HOME="/home/ahmed"
declare -x IM_CONFIG_PHASE="1"
declare -x INSTANCE="Unity"
declare -x JOB="gnome-session"
declare -x LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LANGUAGE="en_US"
declare -x LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/ahmed/catkin_ws/devel/lib:/home/ahmed/catkin_ws/devel/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/opt/ros/indigo/lib:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages=/home/ahmed/catkin_ws/devel/lib:/home/ahmed/catkin_ws/devel/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/opt/ros/indigo/lib:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/lib"
declare -x LESSCLOSE="/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s"
declare -x LESSOPEN="| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s"
declare -x LOGNAME="ahmed"
declare -x LS_COLORS="rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:"
declare -x MANDATORY_PATH="/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path"
declare -x NINJABLOCK_BRIDGE_GLOBAL_ADDRESS="localhost"
declare -x NINJABLOCK_BRIDGE_GLOBAL_PORT="5555"
declare -x NINJABLOCK_BRIDGE_LOCAL_ADDRESS="localhost"
declare -x NINJABLOCK_BRIDGE_LOCAL_PORT="5555"
declare -x NINJABLOCK_TARGET_CONFIG="/opt/ros/indigo/share/rocon_ninjablock_bridge/resources/default.json"
declare -x OLDPWD
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/home/ahmed/catkin_ws/devel/bin:/opt/ros/indigo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
declare -x PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/home/ahmed/catkin_ws/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/home/ahmed/catkin_ws/devel/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig"
declare -x PWD="/home/ahmed"
declare -x PYTHONPATH="/home/ahmed/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"
declare -x QT4_IM_MODULE="xim"
declare -x QT_IM_MODULE="ibus"
declare -x QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME="appmenu-qt5"
declare -x ROCON_RTSP_CAMERA_RELAY_URL="rtsp://user:password<at>localhost:port/videoMain "
declare -x ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES="/home/ahmed/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp"
declare -x ROS_DISTRO="indigo"
declare -x ROS_ETC_DIR="/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros"
declare -x ROS_MASTER_URI="http://localhost:11311"
declare -x ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="/home/ahmed/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks"
declare -x ROS_ROOT="/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros"
declare -x SELINUX_INIT="YES"
declare -x SESSIONTYPE="gnome-session"
declare -x SHELL="/bin/bash"
declare -x SHLVL="1"
declare -x SMARTTHINGS_BRIDGE_GLOBAL_ADDRESS="localhost"
declare -x SMARTTHINGS_BRIDGE_GLOBAL_PORT="5566"
declare -x SMARTTHINGS_BRIDGE_LOCAL_ADDRESS="localhost"
declare -x SMARTTHINGS_BRIDGE_LOCAL_PORT="5566"
declare -x SMARTTHINGS_TARGET_CONFIG="/opt/ros/indigo/share/rocon_smartthings_bridge/resources/default.json"
declare -x SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/1000/keyring-LjhWLh/ssh"
declare -x TERM="xterm"
declare -x TEXTDOMAIN="im-config"
declare -x TEXTDOMAINDIR="/usr/share/locale/"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR="asus_xtion_pro"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_BASE="kobuki"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_BATTERY="/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_GAZEBO_MAP_FILE="/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_gazebo/maps/playground.yaml"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_GAZEBO_WORLD_FILE="/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/playground.world"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_INTERACTIONS_LIST="[turtlebot_bringup/admin.interactions, turtlebot_bringup/documentation.interactions, turtlebot_bringup/pairing.interactions, turtlebot_bringup/visualisation.interactions]"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_MAP_FILE="/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_navigation/maps/willow-2010-02-18-0.10.yaml"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_NAME="turtlebot"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_RAPP_PACKAGE_BLACKLIST="[]"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_RAPP_PACKAGE_WHITELIST="[rocon_apps, turtlebot_rapps]"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_SERIAL_PORT="/dev/kobuki"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_SIMULATION="false"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_STACKS="hexagons"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_STAGE_MAP_FILE="/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_stage/maps/maze.yaml"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_STAGE_WORLD_FILE="/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_stage/maps/stage/maze.world"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_STDR_MAP_FILE="/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_stdr/maps/sparse_obstacles.yaml"
declare -x TURTLEBOT_TYPE="turtlebot"
declare -x UPSTART_EVENTS="started starting"
declare -x UPSTART_INSTANCE=""
declare -x UPSTART_JOB="unity-settings-daemon"
declare -x UPSTART_SESSION="unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1742"
declare -x USER="ahmed"
declare -x VTE_VERSION="3409"
declare -x WINDOWID="54530742"
declare -x XAUTHORITY="/home/ahmed/.Xauthority"
declare -x XDG_CONFIG_DIRS="/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg"
declare -x XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="Unity"
declare -x XDG_DATA_DIRS="/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/"
declare -x XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR="/var/lib/lightdm-data/ahmed"
declare -x XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"
declare -x XDG_SEAT="seat0"
declare -x XDG_SEAT_PATH="/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_ID="c2"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_PATH="/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0"
declare -x XDG_VTNR="7"
declare -x XMODIFIERS="@im=ibus"
```

These are lines I add at the end of my bashrc file for a project I'm working on

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
#export ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
#source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
#source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
#export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
#export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.0.111
#export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:/home/ahmed/gps:/home/ahmed/gps/src/gps_agent_pkg

export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/ahmed/gps:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/ahmed/gps/src/gps_agent_pkg:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH
export 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/lib
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH
export 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/lib

# added by Anaconda2 4.0.0 installer
export PATH="/home/ahmed/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"
export CAFFE_ROOT=/home/ahmed/caffe
export PYTHONPATH=$CAFFE_ROOT/python:$PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: It looks like you have an empty `declare -x` somewhere in one of your shell initialization files (`~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile` etc.). From `help declare`: *If no NAMEs are given, display the attributes and values of all variables.*

Comment: Hi :) Thanks for taking the time to answer me.
I open the files you mentioned but there doesn't seem to be a `declare -x` of any sort :/

Comment: Also check in `~/.profile`

Comment: I did. No `declare -x` there too :/

Comment: Look for `set -x`

Comment: I'll edit my post to include lines I add for a project I'm working on.

Comment: P.s Also no `set -x`

Answer (score 1):

Answering this in case someone runs into a similar problem

The problem was with the lines

```
export 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/lib
```

and

```
export 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/lib
```

They should be

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/lib

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/lib
```